# PivotTable.js usage in Vue 3 (jquery pivot() is not a function)

Tags: javascript, jquery, vue.js, vuejs3, pivottable.js

I'm trying to integrate [PivotTable.js](https://pivottable.js.org/examples/) inside my Vue 3 project. It just does not work.

I Installed jquery and pivottable from npm and when I call $("#output").pivot(--settings---) it just says that pivot() is not a function for jquery.

Can anyone help me?

P.S. I found some vue implementations of the pivottable js but they are in Vue 2 and I had a lot of issues trying to migrate it to Vue 3. That's why I'm trying to integrate directly

Comment: `I Installed jquery and pivottable from npm` ... how did you include them in the page?

Comment: I didn't undestand how ti import the pivottable but I imported jquery like this: ```import $ from 'jquery'```

Comment: you probably just need to `import from 'pivottable'` then

Comment: Import what? I'm not sure i can just leave empty import

The method from pivottable should be integrated somehow into jquery so i'm not sure how to do that here.

Comment: as I said, you probably just need to `import 'pivottable'` ... there isn't a what (sorry, the `from` should not have been there - you're importing for side effects only - read MDN docs on import if you don't understand that sentence)

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Comment: import 'pivottable worked. Thank you very much